# JSONException: Value Array cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

is my 2nd day with this problem.

I receive this at LogCat:

> > Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

i'm doing query's to my database, and put the info that matters to me on an array like this:

```
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):  result= Array
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902): (
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):     [0] => Array
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):         (
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [0] => 7
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [1] => mouse
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [2] => Barcelona
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [3] => Abbey IV Ale Yeast
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [4] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [5] => Ale
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [6] => 11
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [7] => 20
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [8] => prueba
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [9] => Admiral
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [10] => Ahtanum
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [11] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [12] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [13] => 80
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [14] => 20
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [15] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [16] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [17] => Amber Dry Extract
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [18] => Biscuit Malt
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [19] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):         )
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):     [1] => Array
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):         (
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [0] => 8
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [1] => mouse
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [2] => Barcelona
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [3] => Abbey IV Ale Yeast
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [4] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [5] => Ale
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [6] => 50
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [7] => 8
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [8] => prueba2
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [9] => Ahtanum
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [10] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [11] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [12] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [13] => 100
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [14] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [15] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [16] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [17] => Black (Patent) Malt
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [18] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [19] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):         )
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):     [2] => Array
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):         (
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [0] => 9
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [1] => mouse
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [2] => Valencia
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [3] => Abbey Ale
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [4] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [5] => Lager
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [6] => 33
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [7] => 4
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [8] => prueba3
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [9] => Admiral
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [10] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [11] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [12] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [13] => 100
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [14] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [15] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [16] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [17] => Aromatic Malt
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [18] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):             [19] => vacio
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902):         )
07-07 21:01:00.686: E/getpostresponse(17902): )
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$resut = array();
$result = $db->cervezas($user);//this function returns the array
print_r($result);
//$json_data = array();
//  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//      array_push($json_data, $row);
//  }

//$json_data = json_encode($json_data);

$json_data = json_encode($result);
echo $json_data;
```

And i give you the Java code too. The code run after call an Asyntask:

```
public boolean cervezastatus(){
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postparameters2send= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipo","agua"));
    SharedPreferences prefe=getSharedPreferences("datos",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String user = prefe.getString("user","");
    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",user));
    String URL_connect="http://"+IP_Server+"/pide_cerveza.php";

    jdata=post.getserverdata(postparameters2send, URL_connect);

    if (jdata != null) { 
       for (int i=0;i<jdata.length();i++){ 
            try {
                Cerveza cerveza2 = new Cerveza();

                cerveza2.setIdcerveza(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idcerveza"));
                cerveza2.setUsuario(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("usuario"));
                cerveza2.setAgua(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("agua"));
                cerveza2.setLevadura(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("levadura"));
                cerveza2.setFecha(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("fecha"));
                cerveza2.setTipo(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipo"));
                cerveza2.setIbu(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ibu"));
                cerveza2.setCantidad(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("cantidad"));
                cerveza2.setNombre(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"));
                cerveza2.setLupulo(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("lupulo"));
                cerveza2.setLupulo1(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("lupulo1"));
                cerveza2.setLupulo2(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("lupulo2"));
                cerveza2.setLupulo3(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("lupulo3"));
              cerveza2.setLupulo_porc(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("lupulo_porc"));
            cerveza2.setLupulo1_porc(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("lupulo1_porc"));
            cerveza2.setLupulo2_porc(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("lupulo2_porc"));
            cerveza2.setLupulo3_porc(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("lupulo3_porc"));
                cerveza2.setGrano(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("grano"));
                cerveza2.setGrano1(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("grano1"));
                cerveza2.setGrano2(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("grano2"));
                cerveza2.setGrano3(jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("grano3"));

                cerveza_lista.add(cerveza2);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           } 
        } 
        if (jdata!=null && jdata.length() > 0){
            Log.e("no es null","dentro del if");
            JSONObject json_data; //creamos un objeto JSON

            try {
                json_data = jdata.getJSONObject(1);
                String cervezaArray=json_data.getString("Nombre");//accedemos al valor 

                Log.e("longitud", "long= "+jdata.length());
                Log.e("pruebaebeba","psaiaiaia= "+cervezaArray);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
                return true;
          }else{    //json obtenido invalido verificar parte WEB.
                     Log.e("JSON  ", "ERROR");
                    return false;
          }
     }
```

EDIT:

My logcat log without print_r($result)

```
07-07 22:52:20.506: E/getpostresponse(17902):  result= [["7","mouse","Barcelona","Abbey IV Ale Yeast","0000-00-00 00:00:00","Ale","11","20","prueba","Admiral","Ahtanum","vacio","vacio","80","20","vacio","vacio","Amber Dry Extract","Biscuit Malt","vacio"],["8","mouse","Barcelona","Abbey IV Ale Yeast","0000-00-00 00:00:00","Ale","50","8","prueba2","Ahtanum","vacio","vacio","vacio","100","vacio","vacio","vacio","Black (Patent) Malt","vacio","vacio"],["9","mouse","Valencia","Abbey Ale","0000-00-00 00:00:00","Lager","33","4","prueba3","Admiral","vacio","vacio","vacio","100","vacio","vacio","vacio","Aromatic Malt","vacio","vacio"]]
07-07 22:52:20.506: E/DEspues de recibir jdata(17902): fail
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902): org.json.JSONException: Value     ["7","mouse","Barcelona","Abbey IV Ale Yeast","0000-00-00 00:00:00","Ale","11","20","prueba","Admiral","Ahtanum","vacio","vacio","80","20","vacio","vacio","Amber Dry Extract","Biscuit Malt","vacio"] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:514)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen.cervezastatus(HiScreen.java:302)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:200)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:1)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902): org.json.JSONException: Value ["8","mouse","Barcelona","Abbey IV Ale Yeast","0000-00-00 00:00:00","Ale","50","8","prueba2","Ahtanum","vacio","vacio","vacio","100","vacio","vacio","vacio","Black (Patent) Malt","vacio","vacio"] at 1 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:514)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen.cervezastatus(HiScreen.java:302)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:200)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:1)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-07 22:52:20.516: W/System.err(17902):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902): org.json.JSONException: Value ["9","mouse","Valencia","Abbey Ale","0000-00-00 00:00:00","Lager","33","4","prueba3","Admiral","vacio","vacio","vacio","100","vacio","vacio","vacio","Aromatic Malt","vacio","vacio"] at 2 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:514)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen.cervezastatus(HiScreen.java:302)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:200)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:1)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-07 22:52:20.526: E/no es null(17902): dentro del if
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902): org.json.JSONException: Value ["8","mouse","Barcelona","Abbey IV Ale Yeast","0000-00-00 00:00:00","Ale","50","8","prueba2","Ahtanum","vacio","vacio","vacio","100","vacio","vacio","vacio","Black (Patent) Malt","vacio","vacio"] at 1 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:514)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen.cervezastatus(HiScreen.java:336)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:200)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at test.Droidlogin.HiScreen$asynccerveza.doInBackground(HiScreen.java:1)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-07 22:52:20.526: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-07 22:52:20.536: W/System.err(17902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-07 22:52:20.536: W/System.err(17902):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

EDIT 2: My function

```
public function cervezas($user){
//Obtenemos el idusuario en funcion al nombre de usuario que nos pasan
    $iduser_aux = mysql_query("SELECT idusuario FROM usuarios WHERE username='".$user."'")or die("query failed");
    $id_user_res = mysql_fetch_row($iduser_aux);
    $iduser = $id_user_res[0];

    //Creamos vector inicializando todos los valores a "". Este será el vector a devolver al final. 
    /*
    0->idcerveza, 1->usuario, 2->agua, 3->levadura, 4->fecha, 5->tipo, 6->ibu, 7->cantidad, 8->nombre, 9->lupulo, 10->lupulo1, 11->lupulo2, 12->lupulo3, 
    13->lupulo_porc, 14->lupulo1_porc, 15->lupulo2_porc, 16->lupulo3_porc, 17->grano, 18->grano1, 19->grano2, 20->grano3
    */
    $array = array(
        array("vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio"),
        array("vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio"),
        array("vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio", "vacio"),
    );


    //Seleccionamos todas las cerverzas que ha creado un usuario. Puede ser 0,1 o muchas
    $cervezas_aux = mysql_query("SELECT c.idcerveza, (SELECT username FROM usuarios WHERE idusuario='".$iduser."') usuario, 
    (SELECT Ciudad FROM agua WHERE idagua=c.idagua) agua, (SELECT Nombre FROM levadura WHERE idlevadura=c.idlevadura) levadura, 
    c.fecha, c.tipo, c.ibu, c.cantidad, c.nombre FROM cerveza c WHERE idusuario='".$iduser."'")or die("Query failed");
    //$cervezas = mysql_fetch_array($cervezas_aux);
    $t=0;
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($cervezas_aux)){
            //echo $row->idcerveza;
            $array[$t][0] = $row->idcerveza;//Metemos idcerveza en el array
            $array[$t][1] = $row->usuario;//Metemos usuario en el array
            $array[$t][2] = $row->agua;
            $array[$t][3] = $row->levadura;//Metemos levadura en el array
            $array[$t][4] = $row->fecha;//Metemos fecha en el array
            $array[$t][5] = $row->tipo;//Metemos tipo en el array
            $array[$t][6] = $row->ibu;//Metemos ibu en el array
            $array[$t][7] = $row->cantidad;//Metemos cantidad en el array
            $array[$t][8] = $row->nombre;//Metemos nombre en el array
            //$t++;
    //  }
    //$i=0;


    //foreach((array) $cervezas_aux as $cerveza ){

        //Como solo nos falta por meter el lupulo, porcentaje y grano, debemos consultar primero cuanto hay de cada tipo
        $lupulo_cont = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(l.idlupulo) FROM cerveza c, lupulo_has_cerveza l WHERE c.idcerveza = l.idcerveza AND l.idcerveza = '".$array[$t][0]."' ")or die("Query failed1"); 
        $count_lupulo = mysql_fetch_row($lupulo_cont);

        $grano_cont = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(g.idgrano) FROM cerveza c, cerveza_has_grano g WHERE c.idcerveza = g.idcerveza AND g.idcerveza = '".$array[$t][0]."' ")or die("Query failed2"); 
        $count_grano = mysql_fetch_row($grano_cont);

        if($count_lupulo[0] >= 1 && $count_grano[0] >= 1){
            $lupulos = mysql_query("SELECT (SELECT Nombre FROM lupulo WHERE idlupulo = l.idlupulo) lupulo, l.porcentaje FROM cerveza c, lupulo_has_cerveza l WHERE c.idcerveza = l.idcerveza AND l.idcerveza = '".$array[$t][0]."' "); 
            $cont_l = 1;
            //foreach((array) $lupulos as $z=>$lupulo ){
            while($lu = mysql_fetch_object($lupulos)){
                if($count_lupulo[0] == 1){
                    $array[$i][9] = $lu->lupulo;
                    $array[$i][13] = $lu->porcentaje;
                }else if($count_lupulo[0] == 2){
                    if($cont_l == 1){
                        $array[$i][9] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][13] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l++;
                    }else{
                        $array[$i][10] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][14] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l = 1;
                    }
                }else if($count_lupulo[0] == 3){
                    if($cont_l == 1){
                        $array[$i][9] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][13] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l++;
                    }else if($cont_l == 2){
                        $array[$i][10] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][14] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l++;
                    }else{
                        $array[$i][11] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][15] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l = 1;
                    }
                }else if($count_lupulo[0] == 4){
                    if($cont_l == 1){
                        $array[$i][9] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][13] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l++;
                    }else if($cont_l == 2){
                        $array[$i][10] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][14] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l++;
                    }else if($cont_l == 3){
                        $array[$i][11] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][15] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l++;
                    }else{
                        $array[$i][12] = $lu->lupulo;
                        $array[$i][16] = $lu->porcentaje;
                        $cont_l = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            $granos = mysql_query("SELECT (SELECT Nombre FROM grano WHERE idgrano = g.idgrano) grano FROM cerveza c, cerveza_has_grano g WHERE c.idcerveza = g.idcerveza AND g.idcerveza = '".$array[$t][0]."' "); 
            $cont_g = 1;
            //foreach((array) $granos as $j=>$grano ){
            while($gr = mysql_fetch_object($granos)){
                if($count_grano[0] == 1){
                    $array[$i][17] = $gr->grano;
                }else if($count_grano[0] == 2){
                    if($cont_g == 1){
                        $array[$i][17] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g++;
                    }else{
                        $array[$i][18] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g = 1;
                    }
                }else if($count_grano[0] == 3){
                    if($cont_g == 1){
                        $array[$i][17] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g++;
                    }else if($cont_g == 2){
                        $array[$i][18] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g++;
                    }else{
                        $array[$i][19] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g = 1;
                    }
                }else if($count_grano[0] == 4){
                    if($cont_g == 1){
                        $array[$i][17] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g++;
                    }else if($cont_g == 2){
                        $array[$i][18] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g++;
                    }else if($cont_g == 3){
                        $array[$i][19] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g++;
                    }else{
                        $array[$i][20] = $gr->grano;
                        $cont_g = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        $i++;
        $t++;
    }
    //print_r($array);
    return $array;
}
```

EDIT 3:
I change array declaration:
$array = array(); instead of $array = array( array("vacio", "vacio", ...).
And now i recieve a result like JSON Format:

```
result= [{"0":"7","1":"mouse","2":"Barcelona","3":"Abbey IV Ale Yeast","4":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","5":"Ale","6":"11","7":"20","8":"prueba","9":"Admiral","13":"80","10":"Ahtanum","14":"20","17":"Amber Dry Extract","18":"Biscuit Malt"},{"0":"8","1":"mouse","2":"Barcelona","3":"Abbey IV Ale Yeast","4":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","5":"Ale","6":"50","7":"8","8":"prueba2","9":"Ahtanum","13":"100","17":"Black (Patent) Malt"},{"0":"9","1":"mouse","2":"Valencia","3":"Abbey Ale","4":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","5":"Lager","6":"33","7":"4","8":"prueba3","9":"Admiral","13":"100","17":"Aromatic Malt"}]
```

But still throwing me error because there are missing keys. But format is right(I think).
If i do this:

```
$array[$t][9] = $vacio;
$array[$t][10] = $vacio;
$array[$t][11] = $vacio;
$array[$t][12] = $vacio;
$array[$t][13] = $vacio;
$array[$t][14] = $vacio;
$array[$t][15] = $vacio;
$array[$t][16] = $vacio;
$array[$t][17] = $vacio;
$array[$t][18] = $vacio;
$array[$t][19] = $vacio;
$array[$t][20] = $vacio;
```

The array format change again to an Array format.

Please, i need your help. I don't know what can i do anymore.
Thank you.

Comment: Your `logcat` log is showing a PHP, exploded array variable, there's something wrong with the PHP code.

Comment: My logcat log is showing the exploded array because i put print_r($result); if i comment this line doesn't appear.

Comment: Please remove the `print_r($result);` line, I want to see the JSON data you're getting, if you need to protect proprietary data use some string substitution..

Comment: You're sending `JSONArray` rather than `JSONObject` with Name and Value associations.

Comment: Ok, forgive me but then what am I supposed to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a JSONArray type to a JSONObject -> that won't work.

If you are unsure, you can test for first character being `[` (implying JSONArray type) or `{` (implying JSONObject type), and do your parsing accordingly. Alternatively, you can convert a JSONArray type to a JSONObject by simply wrapping the JSONString between `{` and `}` (if not already wrapped) to avoid parsing errors.

The most common problems with JSON data in general (each what I have encountered before) are the following:

1. extra (invisible) characters - try trimming your data
2. header mismatch (while PHP is concerned add `header("Content-Type:application/json");` before echoing out the results)
3. invalid character-set (make sure UTF-8 encoding is in place for your JSON string)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array of arrays so there isnt any object you can access.

It is pretty much useless if the values aren't paired up.

Not sure how you fetch the data, but it is better to build associative arrays then encode it into json in php.

so for example you can use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`